# Windows Icons for Details, List, etc

Tags: icons

You know how, in windows explorer, when you click that button, and drag the slider, you can change the display from details, to list, small icons, etc etc?

Does anyone know where I can get the *icons* that are beside each of those choices?  Windows 7 would be ideal (not sure if they've changed over the years).

Thanks!

Comment: I am sure they are copyrighted by Microsoft. If you don't care about copyrights, just do a screen grab and steal them.

Comment: What does copyrighted mean??  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the icons in "c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll".